# GoRouter navigation not working, although there is no errors in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, routes, navigation, flutter-go-router

Navigation doesn't work. I added `GoRouter.of(context).goNamed(AppPage.profile.toName)` to the button to navigate by name but nothing happens. Not even errors. I tried using push, go, goNamed but nothing helps at all and navigation doesn't work. There are no errors either. Tell me what could be the problem?

**router**

```
class AppRouter {
  late AuthProvider appService;
  GoRouter get router => _goRouter;

  AppRouter(this.appService);

  late final GoRouter _goRouter = GoRouter(
    refreshListenable: appService,
    initialLocation: AppPage.home.toPath,
    routes: <GoRoute>[
      GoRoute(
        path: AppPage.home.toPath,
        name: AppPage.home.toName,
        builder: (context, state) => const HomePage(),
      ),
      GoRoute(
        path: AppPage.splash.toPath,
        name: AppPage.splash.toName,
        builder: (context, state) => const SplashPage(),
      ),
      GoRoute(
        path: AppPage.login.toPath,
        name: AppPage.login.toName,
        builder: (context, state) => const LoginPage(),
      ),
      GoRoute(
        path: AppPage.map.toPath,
        name: AppPage.map.toName,
        builder: (context, state) => const MapPage(),
      ),
      GoRoute(
        path: AppPage.error.toPath,
        name: AppPage.error.toName,
        builder: (context, state) => ErrorPage(error: state.extra.toString()),
      ),
      GoRoute(
        path: AppPage.profile.toPath,
        name: AppPage.profile.toName,
        builder: (context, state) => const ProfilePage(),
      ),
    ],
    errorBuilder: (context, state) => ErrorPage(error: state.error.toString()),
    redirect: (context, state) {

      final loginLocation = AppPage.login.toPath;
      final homeLocation = AppPage.home.toPath;
      final splashLocation = AppPage.splash.toPath;

      switch (appService.loggedInState) {
        case LoggedInState.loading:
          return splashLocation;
        case LoggedInState.loggedIn:
          return homeLocation;
        case LoggedInState.loggedOut:
          return loginLocation;
      }
    },
  );
}
```

**home**

```
  drawer: Drawer(
    child: ListView(
      children: [
        ListTile(
          title: const Text('Profile'),
          onTap: () {
            GoRouter.of(context).goNamed(AppPage.profile.toName);
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
```

**main**

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  final AuthProvider appState;
  const MyApp({super.key, required this.appState});

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final GoRouter goRouter =
        Provider.of<AppRouter>(context, listen: false).router;

    return ChangeNotifierProvider<AuthProvider>.value(
      value: widget.appState,
      child: MaterialApp.router(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        title: 'Test App',
        routeInformationParser: goRouter.routeInformationParser,
        routeInformationProvider: goRouter.routeInformationProvider,
        routerDelegate: goRouter.routerDelegate,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**home**

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final AuthProvider appState = Provider.of(context, listen: false);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () async {
              await appState.signOut();
            },
            icon: const Icon(Icons.exit_to_app),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      drawer: Drawer(
        child: ListView(
          children: [
            ListTile(
              title: const Text('Profile'),
              onTap: () {
                // context.goNamed(AppPage.profile.toName);
                // context.push('/profile');
                GoRouter.of(context).goNamed(AppPage.profile.toName);
                // GoRouter.of(context).go('/profile');
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      body: const HomeBody(),
    );
  }
}



class HomeBody extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomeBody({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MapPage();
  }
}
```

**map**

```
class MapPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MapPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider<CurrentLocationCubit>(
      create: (context) => CurrentLocationCubit(
        FirestoreDB(),
      ),
      child: const Scaffold(
        body: MapBody(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you added it like `MaterialApp.router(routerConfig: AppRouter.router,...`?

Comment: Yes, I added. I updated the code you can see.

Answer (score 4):

As @Peter Koltai suggested you have forgotten adding the actual route.

```
MaterialApp.router(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        title: 'Test App',
        //routeInformationParser: goRouter.routeInformationParser,
        //routeInformationProvider: goRouter.routeInformationProvider,
        //routerDelegate: goRouter.routerDelegate,
        routerConfig : goRouter                    //  You are missing this
      ),
```

Comment: But when I added it I got this error https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKK3P.png

Comment: @Max, just keep the `routerConfig` and remove the rest, as in my edited post.

Comment: The error is gone. But again, for some reason, navigation does not occur GoRouter.of(context).goNamed(AppPage.profile.toName);

Comment: I have updated the layout code of my screens is there a problem with the layout that I am trying to navigate from HomePage even though I have MapPage open?

Comment: Just try `context.goNamed(AppPage.profile.toName);` because it is supposed to work.

Comment: I guess `return ChangeNotifierProvider<AuthProvider>.value(
      value: widget.appState,`, is the one causing the trouble, I am not well equipped with knowledge of provider. But I could suggest you use the Material.router as parent of all the router, try shifting it to the stop, have all the provider related things below Materil.router. I guess this should potentionally solve your problem. Because except that there is no blind spot for me to suggest as everything is good.

Comment: I understood in which direction to move, the problem is in the redirect yet. Thanks for the help!